# How do I get NGINX to properly rewrite and execute on a custom PHP application?

Tags: php, nginx

We have a custom PHP application that we wrote and runs on Apache with .htaccess files to handle the url rewrites. We are trying to convert it to work under NGINX with FPM under Plesk Onyx.

The application generates links like:

```
https://somedomain.com/mypage   (same as index/mypage)
https://somedomain.com/index/sitemap
https://somedomain.com/blog/some-article-name
```

These URL's map to index.php files that take the request_uri and use it to render the page responses.

The structure of the application is nested as follows:

```
docroot (/)

 ./index.php //handler for the request in /

 ./blog/index.php //handler for any request to /blog
```

Each index.php expects to receive a ?path={request_uri} so that it can map the request to the controllers and actions.

I have tried multiple ways to get NGINX to do this using tryfiles and rewrite, but no luck. Using rewrite I can get / to work, but it wont render /mypage or /index/sitemap.

If I try to hit /index/sitemap it downloads the index.php instead of executing it, and if I try the blog the same thing happens. In fact the only path that works is /, all others just download the index.php file.

Here is my configuration as it is now, where am I going wrong?

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control “public”;
    try_files $uri @fallback;
}

location / {
    #index index.php index.html index.html;
    rewrite ^/([^?]*) /index.php?path=$1 break;
    rewrite ^blog/([^?]*) /blog/index.php?path=$1 break;
    #try_files $uri @fallback;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration has multiple issues. I will ignore the first `location` block as it seems to have nothing to do with your question.

The first `rewrite` will always match, so the second `rewrite` will never be consulted. The second `rewrite` will never match anyway, as `nginx` URIs always begin with a `/`. The `[^?]` is meaningless, because `rewrite` uses a normalised URI which does not include the `?` or query string. Using `rewrite...break` means that the rewritten URI is processed within the same location, which is an error as this location is not equipped to process PHP files. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

A solution using `try_files` might look like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?path=$uri&$args;
}
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?path=$uri&$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.